# Dismissing a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a simple done button and defined this action to dismiss the view controller. The code is right but I do not know why the view controller is not dismissed. Can anybody help me?

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(UIButton *)sender {    
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this on the view controller you are trying to dismiss ?

Comment: Was the controller you have this code in presented in the first place?

Comment: I am calling it on the view controller, I want to dismiss. No the controller is not in the first place

Comment: The controller is not present on in the first place, so then there is nothing to dismiss if it is not even present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The window that I want to dismiss should have segue "model". I am using the "push" segue. Simply changing the segue type from "push" to "model" solves my problem.